# How to make multiple Axios requests using a dynamic array of links in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

`linksArray` is an array with six links.

I want to use this array to perform (6) get requests. Then, I want to take the response and `setState` after the response is mapped through to get the results I want.

Any help here?

```
getGistsDescriptions = () => {
let promiseArray = linksArray.map((url) => { return axios.get(url)});

axios.all(promiseArray)
     .then(axios.spread((...res) => {
       console.log(...res);

      /*let temp = res.map((element) => {
        return element.data;
      });*/

       //this.setState({ gistsDescriptions: temp });
     }))
     .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 }
```

I also tried this:

```
getGistsDescriptions = () => {
let promiseArray = linksArray.map((url) => { return axios.get(url)});

axios.all(promiseArray)
     .then((results) => {
       console.log(results);

      /*let temp = results.map((element) => {
        return element.data;
      });*/

       //this.setState({ gistsDescriptions: temp });
     })
     .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you console.log the res in the first code?

Comment: I get an empty array and/or undefined

Comment: can you try it with axios.all([axios.get(url1), axios.get(url2),...]) and see if res  actually gets resolved?

Comment: Also, would you consider a solution that uses fetch and promises?

Comment: axios.all([axios.get(url1), axios.get(url2),...]), this works... but the links are dynamic, I don't know how many links I will need to get in the .all.

Comment: I don't mind a solution using fetch and promises

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First thing you should do is to check whether links array contains actually contains valid links.

The following code works for me:

```js
/* axios v0.16.2 | (c) 2017 by Matt Zabriskie */
!function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],t):"object"==typeof exports?exports.axios=t():e.axios=t()}(this,function(){return function(e){function t(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var o=n[r]={exports:{},id:r,loaded:!1};return e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,t),o.loaded=!0,o.exports}var n={};return t.m=e,t.c=n,t.p="",t(0)}([function(e,t,n){e.exports=n(1)},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e){var t=new s(e),n=i(s.prototype.request,t);return o.extend(n,s.prototype,t),o.extend(n,t),n}var o=n(2),i=n(3),s=n(5),u=n(6),a=r(u);a.Axios=s,a.create=function(e){return r(o.merge(u,e))},a.Cancel=n(23),a.CancelToken=n(24),a.isCancel=n(20),a.all=function(e){return Promise.all(e)},a.spread=n(25),e.exports=a,e.exports.default=a},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e){return"[object Array]"===R.call(e)}function o(e){return"[object ArrayBuffer]"===R.call(e)}function i(e){return"undefined"!=typeof FormData&&e instanceof FormData}function s(e){var t;return t="undefined"!=typeof ArrayBuffer&&ArrayBuffer.isView?ArrayBuffer.isView(e):e&&e.buffer&&e.buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer}function u(e){return"string"==typeof e}function a(e){return"number"==typeof e}function c(e){return"undefined"==typeof e}function f(e){return null!==e&&"object"==typeof e}function p(e){return"[object Date]"===R.call(e)}function d(e){return"[object File]"===R.call(e)}function l(e){return"[object Blob]"===R.call(e)}function h(e){return"[object Function]"===R.call(e)}function m(e){return f(e)&&h(e.pipe)}function y(e){return"undefined"!=typeof URLSearchParams&&e instanceof URLSearchParams}function w(e){return e.replace(/^\s*/,"").replace(/\s*$/,"")}function v(){return("undefined"==typeof navigator||"ReactNative"!==navigator.product)&&("undefined"!=typeof window&&"undefined"!=typeof document)}function g(e,t){if(null!==e&&"undefined"!=typeof e)if("object"==typeof e||r(e)||(e=[e]),r(e))for(var n=0,o=e.length;n<o;n++)t.call(null,e[n],n,e);else for(var i in e)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,i)&&t.call(null,e[i],i,e)}function x(){function e(e,n){"object"==typeof t[n]&&"object"==typeof e?t[n]=x(t[n],e):t[n]=e}for(var t={},n=0,r=arguments.length;n<r;n++)g(arguments[n],e);return t}function b(e,t,n){return g(t,function(t,r){n&&"function"==typeof t?e[r]=E(t,n):e[r]=t}),e}var E=n(3),C=n(4),R=Object.prototype.toString;e.exports={isArray:r,isArrayBuffer:o,isBuffer:C,isFormData:i,isArrayBufferView:s,isString:u,isNumber:a,isObject:f,isUndefined:c,isDate:p,isFile:d,isBlob:l,isFunction:h,isStream:m,isURLSearchParams:y,isStandardBrowserEnv:v,forEach:g,merge:x,extend:b,trim:w}},function(e,t){"use strict";e.exports=function(e,t){return function(){for(var n=new Array(arguments.length),r=0;r<n.length;r++)n[r]=arguments[r];return e.apply(t,n)}}},function(e,t){function n(e){return!!e.constructor&&"function"==typeof e.constructor.isBuffer&&e.constructor.isBuffer(e)}function r(e){return"function"==typeof e.readFloatLE&&"function"==typeof e.slice&&n(e.slice(0,0))}/*!
  * Determine if an object is a Buffer
  *
  * @author   Feross Aboukhadijeh <feross@feross.org> <http://feross.org>
  * @license  MIT
  */
e.exports=function(e){return null!=e&&(n(e)||r(e)||!!e._isBuffer)}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e){this.defaults=e,this.interceptors={request:new s,response:new s}}var o=n(6),i=n(2),s=n(17),u=n(18),a=n(21),c=n(22);r.prototype.request=function(e){"string"==typeof e&&(e=i.merge({url:arguments[0]},arguments[1])),e=i.merge(o,this.defaults,{method:"get"},e),e.method=e.method.toLowerCase(),e.baseURL&&!a(e.url)&&(e.url=c(e.baseURL,e.url));var t=[u,void 0],n=Promise.resolve(e);for(this.interceptors.request.forEach(function(e){t.unshift(e.fulfilled,e.rejected)}),this.interceptors.response.forEach(function(e){t.push(e.fulfilled,e.rejected)});t.length;)n=n.then(t.shift(),t.shift());return n},i.forEach(["delete","get","head","options"],function(e){r.prototype[e]=function(t,n){return this.request(i.merge(n||{},{method:e,url:t}))}}),i.forEach(["post","put","patch"],function(e){r.prototype[e]=function(t,n,r){return this.request(i.merge(r||{},{method:e,url:t,data:n}))}}),e.exports=r},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e,t){!i.isUndefined(e)&&i.isUndefined(e["Content-Type"])&&(e["Content-Type"]=t)}function o(){var e;return"undefined"!=typeof XMLHttpRequest?e=n(8):"undefined"!=typeof process&&(e=n(8)),e}var i=n(2),s=n(7),u={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},a={adapter:o(),transformRequest:[function(e,t){return s(t,"Content-Type"),i.isFormData(e)||i.isArrayBuffer(e)||i.isBuffer(e)||i.isStream(e)||i.isFile(e)||i.isBlob(e)?e:i.isArrayBufferView(e)?e.buffer:i.isURLSearchParams(e)?(r(t,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"),e.toString()):i.isObject(e)?(r(t,"application/json;charset=utf-8"),JSON.stringify(e)):e}],transformResponse:[function(e){if("string"==typeof e)try{e=JSON.parse(e)}catch(e){}return e}],timeout:0,xsrfCookieName:"XSRF-TOKEN",xsrfHeaderName:"X-XSRF-TOKEN",maxContentLength:-1,validateStatus:function(e){return e>=200&&e<300}};a.headers={common:{Accept:"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},i.forEach(["delete","get","head"],function(e){a.headers[e]={}}),i.forEach(["post","put","patch"],function(e){a.headers[e]=i.merge(u)}),e.exports=a},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(2);e.exports=function(e,t){r.forEach(e,function(n,r){r!==t&&r.toUpperCase()===t.toUpperCase()&&(e[t]=n,delete e[r])})}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(2),o=n(9),i=n(12),s=n(13),u=n(14),a=n(10),c="undefined"!=typeof window&&window.btoa&&window.btoa.bind(window)||n(15);e.exports=function(e){return new Promise(function(t,f){var p=e.data,d=e.headers;r.isFormData(p)&&delete d["Content-Type"];var l=new XMLHttpRequest,h="onreadystatechange",m=!1;if("undefined"==typeof window||!window.XDomainRequest||"withCredentials"in l||u(e.url)||(l=new window.XDomainRequest,h="onload",m=!0,l.onprogress=function(){},l.ontimeout=function(){}),e.auth){var y=e.auth.username||"",w=e.auth.password||"";d.Authorization="Basic "+c(y+":"+w)}if(l.open(e.method.toUpperCase(),i(e.url,e.params,e.paramsSerializer),!0),l.timeout=e.timeout,l[h]=function(){if(l&&(4===l.readyState||m)&&(0!==l.status||l.responseURL&&0===l.responseURL.indexOf("file:"))){var n="getAllResponseHeaders"in l?s(l.getAllResponseHeaders()):null,r=e.responseType&&"text"!==e.responseType?l.response:l.responseText,i={data:r,status:1223===l.status?204:l.status,statusText:1223===l.status?"No Content":l.statusText,headers:n,config:e,request:l};o(t,f,i),l=null}},l.onerror=function(){f(a("Network Error",e,null,l)),l=null},l.ontimeout=function(){f(a("timeout of "+e.timeout+"ms exceeded",e,"ECONNABORTED",l)),l=null},r.isStandardBrowserEnv()){var v=n(16),g=(e.withCredentials||u(e.url))&&e.xsrfCookieName?v.read(e.xsrfCookieName):void 0;g&&(d[e.xsrfHeaderName]=g)}if("setRequestHeader"in l&&r.forEach(d,function(e,t){"undefined"==typeof p&&"content-type"===t.toLowerCase()?delete d[t]:l.setRequestHeader(t,e)}),e.withCredentials&&(l.withCredentials=!0),e.responseType)try{l.responseType=e.responseType}catch(t){if("json"!==e.responseType)throw t}"function"==typeof e.onDownloadProgress&&l.addEventListener("progress",e.onDownloadProgress),"function"==typeof e.onUploadProgress&&l.upload&&l.upload.addEventListener("progress",e.onUploadProgress),e.cancelToken&&e.cancelToken.promise.then(function(e){l&&(l.abort(),f(e),l=null)}),void 0===p&&(p=null),l.send(p)})}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(10);e.exports=function(e,t,n){var o=n.config.validateStatus;n.status&&o&&!o(n.status)?t(r("Request failed with status code "+n.status,n.config,null,n.request,n)):e(n)}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(11);e.exports=function(e,t,n,o,i){var s=new Error(e);return r(s,t,n,o,i)}},function(e,t){"use strict";e.exports=function(e,t,n,r,o){return e.config=t,n&&(e.code=n),e.request=r,e.response=o,e}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e){return encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/%40/gi,"@").replace(/%3A/gi,":").replace(/%24/g,"$").replace(/%2C/gi,",").replace(/%20/g,"+").replace(/%5B/gi,"[").replace(/%5D/gi,"]")}var o=n(2);e.exports=function(e,t,n){if(!t)return e;var i;if(n)i=n(t);else if(o.isURLSearchParams(t))i=t.toString();else{var s=[];o.forEach(t,function(e,t){null!==e&&"undefined"!=typeof e&&(o.isArray(e)&&(t+="[]"),o.isArray(e)||(e=[e]),o.forEach(e,function(e){o.isDate(e)?e=e.toISOString():o.isObject(e)&&(e=JSON.stringify(e)),s.push(r(t)+"="+r(e))}))}),i=s.join("&")}return i&&(e+=(e.indexOf("?")===-1?"?":"&")+i),e}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(2);e.exports=function(e){var t,n,o,i={};return e?(r.forEach(e.split("\n"),function(e){o=e.indexOf(":"),t=r.trim(e.substr(0,o)).toLowerCase(),n=r.trim(e.substr(o+1)),t&&(i[t]=i[t]?i[t]+", "+n:n)}),i):i}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(2);e.exports=r.isStandardBrowserEnv()?function(){function e(e){var t=e;return n&&(o.setAttribute("href",t),t=o.href),o.setAttribute("href",t),{href:o.href,protocol:o.protocol?o.protocol.replace(/:$/,""):"",host:o.host,search:o.search?o.search.replace(/^\?/,""):"",hash:o.hash?o.hash.replace(/^#/,""):"",hostname:o.hostname,port:o.port,pathname:"/"===o.pathname.charAt(0)?o.pathname:"/"+o.pathname}}var t,n=/(msie|trident)/i.test(navigator.userAgent),o=document.createElement("a");return t=e(window.location.href),function(n){var o=r.isString(n)?e(n):n;return o.protocol===t.protocol&&o.host===t.host}}():function(){return function(){return!0}}()},function(e,t){"use strict";function n(){this.message="String contains an invalid character"}function r(e){for(var t,r,i=String(e),s="",u=0,a=o;i.charAt(0|u)||(a="=",u%1);s+=a.charAt(63&t>>8-u%1*8)){if(r=i.charCodeAt(u+=.75),r>255)throw new n;t=t<<8|r}return s}var o="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";n.prototype=new Error,n.prototype.code=5,n.prototype.name="InvalidCharacterError",e.exports=r},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(2);e.exports=r.isStandardBrowserEnv()?function(){return{write:function(e,t,n,o,i,s){var u=[];u.push(e+"="+encodeURIComponent(t)),r.isNumber(n)&&u.push("expires="+new Date(n).toGMTString()),r.isString(o)&&u.push("path="+o),r.isString(i)&&u.push("domain="+i),s===!0&&u.push("secure"),document.cookie=u.join("; ")},read:function(e){var t=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(^|;\\s*)("+e+")=([^;]*)"));return t?decodeURIComponent(t[3]):null},remove:function(e){this.write(e,"",Date.now()-864e5)}}}():function(){return{write:function(){},read:function(){return null},remove:function(){}}}()},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(){this.handlers=[]}var o=n(2);r.prototype.use=function(e,t){return this.handlers.push({fulfilled:e,rejected:t}),this.handlers.length-1},r.prototype.eject=function(e){this.handlers[e]&&(this.handlers[e]=null)},r.prototype.forEach=function(e){o.forEach(this.handlers,function(t){null!==t&&e(t)})},e.exports=r},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e){e.cancelToken&&e.cancelToken.throwIfRequested()}var o=n(2),i=n(19),s=n(20),u=n(6);e.exports=function(e){r(e),e.headers=e.headers||{},e.data=i(e.data,e.headers,e.transformRequest),e.headers=o.merge(e.headers.common||{},e.headers[e.method]||{},e.headers||{}),o.forEach(["delete","get","head","post","put","patch","common"],function(t){delete e.headers[t]});var t=e.adapter||u.adapter;return t(e).then(function(t){return r(e),t.data=i(t.data,t.headers,e.transformResponse),t},function(t){return s(t)||(r(e),t&&t.response&&(t.response.data=i(t.response.data,t.response.headers,e.transformResponse))),Promise.reject(t)})}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n(2);e.exports=function(e,t,n){return r.forEach(n,function(n){e=n(e,t)}),e}},function(e,t){"use strict";e.exports=function(e){return!(!e||!e.__CANCEL__)}},function(e,t){"use strict";e.exports=function(e){return/^([a-z][a-z\d\+\-\.]*:)?\/\//i.test(e)}},function(e,t){"use strict";e.exports=function(e,t){return t?e.replace(/\/+$/,"")+"/"+t.replace(/^\/+/,""):e}},function(e,t){"use strict";function n(e){this.message=e}n.prototype.toString=function(){return"Cancel"+(this.message?": "+this.message:"")},n.prototype.__CANCEL__=!0,e.exports=n},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e){if("function"!=typeof e)throw new TypeError("executor must be a function.");var t;this.promise=new Promise(function(e){t=e});var n=this;e(function(e){n.reason||(n.reason=new o(e),t(n.reason))})}var o=n(23);r.prototype.throwIfRequested=function(){if(this.reason)throw this.reason},r.source=function(){var e,t=new r(function(t){e=t});return{token:t,cancel:e}},e.exports=r},function(e,t){"use strict";e.exports=function(e){return function(t){return e.apply(null,t)}}}])});
//# sourceMappingURL=axios.min.map

let linksArr = ['https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments'];

axios.all(linksArr.map(l => axios.get(l)))
  .then(axios.spread(function (...res) {
    // all requests are now complete
    console.log(res);
  }));
```

Alternatively, you can also use fetch and promises

```js
// sample links
let linksArr = [undefined, undefined];

let promiseArr = linksArr.map(l => fetch(l).then(res => res.json()));

Promise.all(promiseArr).then(res => {
  /* do something with res here... */
  console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: This worked, which is how I originally had it set up.. Very strange issue: something was wrong with my array of links, which is why it didn't work.. but the way I set it up in my question, worked for me in the end.. which is very similar to this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer in case some other people have this issue in their project.

Answer (score 5):

## They're just Promises

`axios.all` is basically Axios' polyfill for `Promise.all`. @D-reaper's use of `fetch` could just as easily implement Axios.

```js
const getGistsDescriptions = () => {
  /* 
  I assume `getGistDescriptions` is stored as a variable or a constant. 
  If this is supposed to be a method inside a React component class, 
  the arrow function + equal sign syntax is incorrect.
  */
  let promiseArray = linksArray.map( url=> axios.get(url) );
  Promise.all( promiseArray )
  .then(
    results => {
      const gistsDescriptions = results.map( el => el.data );
      this.setState({ gistsDescriptions })
      /* 
      this is the same as 
      `{ gistsDescriptions: gistsDescriptions }`
      */
      
    }
  )
  .catch(console.log)


}
```

If you're up for a challenge, you also could use `async/await`:

```js
const getGistsDescriptions = async () => {

  const promiseArray = linksArray.map(url=>axios.get(url));
  
  try {
  
    const gistsDescriptions = (
      await Promise.all(promiseArray)
    ).map(res=>res.data)
    
    this.setState({ gistsDescriptions })
    
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
  

}
```